# Django OAuth Toolkit Login Template

Tags: django, templates, authentication, oauth, toolkit

I'm trying to create an OAuth server using the following instructions [here](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html)

Where can I find the login template with path registration/login.html? Is this a template I have to create inside directory /registration? The instructions are not clear but mention that this template should be changed.

Another [post](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/building-oauth2-services-in-django-with-django-oauth-toolkit/), says that when accessing http://localhost:8000/o/applications/, a screen like the following should show up:

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions folks?